# Why is this PHP foreach loop only executing once?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

Trying to debug some issues with WordPress' notorious pseudo-cron. Thought about putting this on WordPressAnswers but I think this is less about WP and more a basic PHP question on a foreach that seems to never get past its first run. (Yes, definitely looked at a bunch of similar questions, but no love there, sorry.)

Here's the code, with 3 checkpoints where I added output for testing. I'm including the entire code of everything in the loop, just to be thorough, though most of it's probably beside the point. Checkpoints 2 and 3 never display for me, and checkpoint 1 only shows up once (i.e. on first iteration of loop). Not shown is where I'm outputting $crons, and count($crons) for good measure, to confirm that, yes, it absolutely has multiple elements.

```
foreach ( $crons as $timestamp => $cronhooks ) {
    echo("<br>loop for timestamp " . $timestamp); // checkpoint 1
    if ( $timestamp > $gmt_time ) {
    break;
        }

    foreach ( $cronhooks as $hook => $keys ) {
    echo("<br>loop for hook " . $hook); // checkpoint 2

        foreach ( $keys as $k => $v ) {

            $schedule = $v['schedule'];

            if ( $schedule != false ) {
                $new_args = array($timestamp, $schedule, $hook, $v['args']);
                call_user_func_array('wp_reschedule_event', $new_args);
            }

            wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, $hook, $v['args'] );

             do_action_ref_array( $hook, $v['args'] );

            // If the hook ran too long and another cron process stole the lock, quit.
            if ( _get_cron_lock() != $doing_wp_cron ) {
                echo("quitting!"); // checkpoint 3
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the output I'm getting from this, despite my 5 elements, is:

> loop for timestamp 1382968401

I'll be grateful for extra eyes on whatever I'm missing. I'm 95% sure this is WP core code, except my checkpoints, although for various reasons it's not out of the question that another programmer was mucking about in here in an end-run around our version control system. A whole other problem, obviously!

Comment: What's the value of `$gmt_time`?

Comment: set via microtime(true). at this instant, per another output checkpoint higher up in my code, 1382918286.117

Comment: Knew it... See my answer below.

Comment: `1382968401 > 1382918286.117` is true so it will `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `foreach` can't be wrong.

The only way your loop could do only one iteration is that it `break`s. And that could only mean that the first `$timestamp` is greater than `$gmt_time`.

*(There's also the `return` possibility near the bottom, but you already said you receive one line of text, so it couldn't have gone that way...)*

I'm guessing that you want to just skip the iteration if the scheduled task is in the future. To do that, just change `break` with `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$gmt_time` is current UTC time, then the timestamp `1382968401` will be greater (as of this writing):

```
$d = new DateTime('@'.'1382968401', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output 2013-10-28 13:53:21
```

Which would explain why your loop breaks on the first iteration.

Comment: oh for pete's.... I thought I'd eliminated that by actually commenting out that break at some point with same results, but trying it again now, yep: output times five. am bracing for the downvote on my Question of Shame. Thanks both. (and sorry I can't upvote your answer.)